# Unsure how to handle not having a connection in Android App

Tags: android, exception, connection, xml-parsing, socketexception

I am making an app that parses an RSS Feed into a SQLite database which is then read from to populate a list of posts. The database is there so that even without a connection, the user can view posts that have been retrieved earlier.

I have put all the parsing into a try-catch; however, when it catches the exception, the application crashes. Is there a way to gracefully handle this exception so it just skips to reading what is in the database? I have looked into using `SocketException` and `XmlPullParserException`, but these either bring more errors or don't affect the problem.

Comment: It's really easy to answer without seeing the code...

Comment: What error is actually getting thrown? Can you post the stacktrace from the logcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which exception is being thrown? You *could* add a generic Exception handler at the end of your try/catch statement. e.g.

```
try {
  //...your code here
} catch (XmlPullParseException xe) {
  //log error
} catch (SocketException se) {
  //log error
} catch (Exception e) {
  //log error
}
```

You could also check for a valid connection before you make the call using the following static method:

```
public static boolean isOnline(Context context) {
   ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
   NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
   if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting())
      return true;
   else
      return false;
}
```

Make sure you add :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

to your android manifest if you use that call